# Adding special character to XML

Tags: xml, groovy

Trying to add `&` as one of the element value but it `StreamMarkupBuilder` does not recognize `&` or `&amp;`
**Code is**

```
def buildXml {
   def requestXml = {
     RootElement {
        Element1("&Value1")
        Element2("Value2")
     }
   }
 return new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind(requestXml)
}
```

**Output is**

```
<RootElement>
  <Element1>&amp;Value1</Element1>
  <Element2>Value2</Element2>
</RootElement>
```

**Expected Output**

```
<RootElement>
      <Element1>&Value1</Element1>
      <Element2>Value2</Element2>
</RootElement>
```

I came across `MarkupBuilder`'s `setEscapeAttributes()` method. Doc says

```
Defaults to true. If set to false then you must escape any special characters within attribute values such as '&', '<', CR/LF, single and double quotes etc. manually as needed. The builder will not guard against producing invalid XML when in this mode and the output may not be able to be parsed/round-tripped but it does give you full control when producing for instance HTML output.
```

Looking for something similar for `StreamMarkupBuilder`

Comment: That is the correct output. What are you expecting?

Comment: @JimGarrison  Added expected output.

Comment: The expected output is not XML, since it is not well-formed. Unescaped `&` characters are not allowed.

Comment: May be not. I am sending this request to a legacy backend which expects `<Element1>` value to start with `&`.

Comment: `setEscapeAttributes` seems to apply to attribute values only, not text nodes.  If the legacy system really cannot cope with `&amp;` in a text node and must see a naked `&` you will probably have to post-process the output. A simple sed command to replace `&amp;` with `&` should suffice.  You are not going to convince a standards compliant serializer to emit a naked `&`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be good with what you have. I second Jim and mzjn. Ultimately the legacy system will be parsing the xml to get the expected  to start with `&` :

```
def requestXml = {
  RootElement {
     Element1("&Value1")
     Element2("Value2")
  }
}

def xml = new groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind(requestXml)

//Legacy backend reading/parsing the xml 
//should reads escaped characters appropriately.
def slurper = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml.toString())
assert slurper.Element1 == "&Value1"
```